# Is there a way to tell my Macbook Pro to automatically toggle trackpad natural scrolling based on the presence of a mouse?

Tags: mac, trackpad, macos

I've got a Macbook pro running Os Ventura. When I use the trackpad directly, I like natural scrolling; when I have a mouse with a scroll wheel I prefer this setting toggled off. Throughout the course of my work day I have opportunities to go back and forth many times and it'd be nice if I could tell it to automatically toggle based on whether a mouse is plugged into the USB. Is there such a configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several 3-rd party apps to make mouse and trackpad have different scroll directions:

[UnnaturalScrollWheels](https://github.com/ther0n/UnnaturalScrollWheels)

[Scroll Reverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/)

[Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org/)

[Mos](https://mos.caldis.me/)

There is even [Shortcut](https://ziga.dev/posts/macos-scroll-reverse/) to switch the setting if you prefer to not install any 3-rd party apps but it requires manual activation.